# What is the Same-Origin Policy for File URIs?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

Perhaps my searching(Google-Fu) has deserted me, but I can't find a good description of the same-origin policy for file URIs other than [this outdated Mozilla page](https://web.archive.org/web/20210301083224/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Misc_top_level/Same-origin_policy_for_file:_URIs).  Can anyone point me to an explanation of the same-origin policy for file URIs?  In particular, if I have a script loaded from (say) file:///C:/Users/Joe/Test/test.html, what files is that script allowed to access using XMLHttpRequest?  And how should I specify the URI, i.e., as relative to the script's URI?

Note that I'm not asking for a way to get around cross-origin restrictions, just an understanding of where I need resources to reside so that I can load them without triggering a cross-origin error.

Comment: You want to look into [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Comment: `file:///` uri's work differently with respect to "same origin policy" in different browsers - chrome has a command line flag to make them "same origin" (as they are in Firefox at least) - other browsers aren't worth talking about :p

Comment: @JaromandaX +1 to your comment, but the irony is that the *other browsers aren't worth talking about*, specifically IE and Edge, happen to be the easiest to use for such a development scenario. They both work smoothly with `file:///` and CORS combination without any need for command line flags or any other steps.

Comment: That's why they aren't worth talking about @RacilHilan - because they work :p

Comment: In response to the suggestion to look at CORS:  That doesn't seem to apply to file URIs.  Am I wrong about that?

Comment: @JaromandaX -- I'm most interested in the Chrome case (since at the moment Chrome is the only browser that can run my application in a reasonable time).  Does Chrome consider all file URIs to be cross-origin unless the --disable-web-security flag has been set?

Comment: I think there's a less dangerous flag, `--allow-file-access-from-files`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same-origin policy for `file:///` URIs is implementation-dependent.

The [W3C's CORS spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) gets its definition of an "origin" from IETF [RFC 6454 "The Web Origin Concept"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6454).  In [section 4 "Origin of a URI"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6454#section-4) it reads:

> 4. If uri-scheme is "file", the implementation MAY return an implementation-defined value.
>
> NOTE: Historically, user agents have granted content from the
> file scheme a tremendous amount of privilege.  However,
> granting all local files such wide privileges can lead to
> privilege escalation attacks.  Some user agents have had
> success granting local files directory-based privileges, but
> this approach has not been widely adopted.  Other user agents
> use globally unique identifiers for each file URI, which is
> the most secure option.

Looking up the behavior (and the reasoning behind it) for specific browsers is not easy.  I actually think the old Mozilla wiki page you referenced is one of the better resources on this topic.  [Here's a fairly helpful discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/0w5mxLMkrNM); general guidance is to assume the browser may treat all `file:///` URIs as totally unique origins.

Comment: This answer is correct but it should be noted that the https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/ spec (published in 2014) is now obsolete. (In general, most specs published in the https://www.w3.org/TR tree are obsolete…) The current requirements for determining the origin of a `file:`-protocol URL are in the URL standard at https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#origin: *“Unfortunate as it is, this is left as an exercise to the reader. When in doubt, return a new opaque origin.”* — in other words, it’s implementation-dependent (as this answer says).

Comment: See also https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/0w5mxLMkrNM