# cannot access rules in external CSSStyleSheet

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I am having trouble figuring out why `.cssRules` and `.rules` won't work in my simplistic color generator project.

I have a `<link>` element to link my external CSS file:

```html
<link href="ColorGenerator.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And a `<script>` element to link my external JS file before the `</html>` element:

```html
<script src="ColorGenerator.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I then have this in my CSS file:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#body {
  background: #E1E1F4;
}
```

And this on the JS file:

```js
const mySheet = document.styleSheets[0];
const body = document.getElementById("body");

body.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    mySheet.rules[0].style.background = "#ffa500";
  }
};
```

But when I press space(`e.keyCode == 32`) nothing happens, so then I open the developer tools in Chrome and I get this error message:

`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'rules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules at HTMLBodyElement.body.onkeydown`

I'm not sure if Chrome just doesn't support it or if I have a failure in my code, eitherway I truly appreciate any help.

Comment: I am not too familiar with `CSSStyleSheet` but the fruitful manual says it has a `cssRules` member, not `rules`. Could that be related?

Comment: I tried using both `.cssRules` and `.rules`, but both of them give me the same error

Comment: In my Firefox 58 it works with `cssRules`; Chromium says “Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet'“”. I do not know why. What browser are you using?

Comment: I think there may be a bug in Chrome 64. I've seen a couple of issues logged on different Github projects that seem to reference the same issue. Good luck.

Comment: Are you doing this in a page served from a server (HTTP or HTTPS)? Or in a page served from the file system (file:// URL)? The latter might be broken and it is generally not a recommended way of browsing, as it is broken (for security purposes) in many aspects.

Comment: It's seems not work at all. I'm 64.0.3282.186

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As of Chrome 64, new CORS rules are enforced for stylesheets. You'll need to use a local development server to do local testing of functionality that depends on the CSS Object Model.  For details, see [Cannot access cssRules from local css file in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48753691/cannot-access-cssrules-from-local-css-file-in-chrome/49160760#49160760).

Answer (score 0):

I just got hit by the same problem. In my case it was possible to use `fetch(the.css)` to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Set crossorigin="anonymous" and it worked for me!