# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'rules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet'

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, cors, cssom

In Code.org's App Lab editor, we recently started seeing this error in Chrome 64:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'rules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet'
```

The error is thrown in this function designed to detect whether CSS media queries are being used by the browser, on the line that includes `styleSheets[i].cssRules`.

```js
/**
 * IE9 throws an exception when trying to access the media field of a stylesheet
 */
export function browserSupportsCssMedia() {
  var styleSheets = document.styleSheets;
  for (var i = 0; i < styleSheets.length; i++) {
    var rules = styleSheets[i].cssRules || styleSheets[i].rules;
    try {
      if (rules.length > 0) {
        // see if we can access media
        rules[0].media;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

The problem has been seen on Windows, OSX, Ubuntu, and ChromeOS; on Chrome versions 64.0.3282.167 and 64.0.3282.186.  However, we've also seen this problem *not* happen on exactly the same Chrome version and platform - and we don't seem to be able to reproduce the problem in an incognito window.

What is the root cause of this error?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This was a good story and a new 'gotcha' for web developers, so I just had to share:

Chrome 64.0.3282.0 (released January 2018, [full change list](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/63.0.3239.150..64.0.3282.0?pretty=fuller&n=10000)) introduced a change to security rules for stylesheets.  I'm irritated that I couldn't find this change in any changelog less detailed than the full commit list.

Commit [a4ebe08](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/a4ebe08c91e29140e700c7bae9b94f27a786d1ca) in Chromium is described:

> Update behavior of CSSStyleSheet to match spec for Security origin
>
> Spec is here:
>   https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-1/#the-cssstylesheet-interface
>
> Updated: the following methods now throw a SecurityError if the
>   style sheet is not accessible:
>
> - cssRules() / rules()
> - insertRule()
> - deleteRule()

This commit is a fix for the bug [Security: Inconsistent CORS implementation regarding CSS and the link element.](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=775525) The linked W3C spec describes in detail where use of the CSS Object Model requires same-origin access.

All that said, why was this issue showing up in App Lab?  We shouldn't experience any CORS issues, because we only load stylesheets from our own origin:

[image: Chrome network tab showing all CSS requested from the affected page]

The final clue was that we couldn't reproduce this issue in a private tab.  We started looking at Chrome extensions and realized that some affected users had the [Loom Video Recorder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/loom-video-recorder-scree/liecbddmkiiihnedobmlmillhodjkdmb?hl=en-US) extension enabled, which seems to inject its own CSS into the page.  Since our (naïve) function was iterating through *all* loaded stylesheets, it was attempting to access this stylesheet injected by the extension and thus causing the CORS error.

That said, there's still some open issues and debate around this change in Chrome:

- [This comment](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=775525#c25) on the original security bug complains that the only way now to detect that the stylesheet is not accessible from JavaScript is with a `try/catch`.
- A Chromium bug opened January 23rd ([document.styleSheets.cssRules is null even with Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=804607)) suggests there may be an implementation issue with the new security rule that breaks certain workarounds.
- The spec being implemented seems pretty stable, but it still has "Working Draft" status so who knows where it will land and what other browsers will implement.

[To fix our problem, we just tore out the entire function.](https://github.com/code-dot-org/code-dot-org/pull/21082)  We don't support IE9 anymore, and we know all of our supported browsers handle media queries properly.

**Related (but not quite duplicate) questions:**

- [cannot access rules in external CSSStyleSheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49088507/cannot-access-rules-in-external-cssstylesheet/49160899)
- [Cannot access cssRules from local css file in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48753691/cannot-access-cssrules-from-local-css-file-in-chrome/49160760)

Comment: If you can't access the rules even with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, you'll need to add the `crossorigin` attribute to the `<link>` tag. Unfortunately, that isn't supported in IE11, in which case you'll need to use a different method, such as requesting the CSS text manually with XHR.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else has this issue related to the Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) policy it is discussed here: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/2296

You will have to test using a local host:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server

Here is the workaround a "try/catch" method:

```js
try {
  var classes = stylesheets[s].rules || stylesheets[s].cssRules;
} catch (e) {
  console.warn("Can't read the css rules of: " + stylesheets[s].href, e);
  continue
}
```

Had this issue and was racking my brain and this seemed to work...Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For me works to move the css link href from header to body tag ending.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href=".....">
</body>
```