# why dom to image library is not capturing font icons. how to fix it

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, screen-capture

I'am doing like this

```
domtoImage.toPng(node)
.then(function(basicStr)
{
   console.log(basicStr);
})
```

In my HTML some of the font icons are there but dom-to-image.js(library)
not capturing those font icons.

how to solve this problem?

please help me

thanks

Comment: you have an example ? 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dom2image
recommend to add catch and see whats wrong
.catch(function (error) {
        console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
 }

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
yes I am having 
.catch(function(error) {
       console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
       
     });
no error

Comment: Error while reading CSS rules from https//:....../css/ui_min.a196f4c9a766f5f62e477b024584cba9.css SecurityError: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules

this error is coming

Comment: great! this can lead you closer to the solution.
apparently Security Error or missing property. redirect you to: 
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48753691/cannot-access-cssrules-from-local-css-file-in-chrome-64/49160760#49160760]
maybe that can fit. best of luck.