# Why does inline JavaScript work while referenced JavaScript errors

Tags: javascript, css

I have two versions of the same html page that are identical except one has the JavaScript included and the other reads the exact same JavaScript from a file. The included version works and the referenced version fails.

Both versions used to work, the error seems to be related to my adding code to get a list of the available animations from the stylesheets. The CSS files with the keyframe animations in them are likewise either included or by reference, corresponding to whether the JavaScript is.

Also note I am testing using `file:///` not `https://`.

**Referenced Version Snippet** Fails

```
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lib/normalise.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/anim.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lib/animate.min.css">
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Included Version Snippet** Works

```
...
<style>
... inline CSS rules including keyframes
</style>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
console.log('>>> BEGIN READING');

// ... code here ommitted, it works

function getAnimationList(){
// Return a list of all of the animation keyframe names in all style sheets.
    var ss = document.styleSheets;
    var anims = [];
    // loop through all the style sheets
    for (var s = 0; s < ss.length; s++) {
        if (ss[s].cssRules) {                 <<<**LINE 32**: ERROR OCCURS IN REFERENCED VERSION
            // loop through all the rules
            for (var r = ss[s].cssRules.length - 1; r >= 0; r--) {
                var rule = ss[s].cssRules[r];
                if ((rule.type === window.CSSRule.KEYFRAMES_RULE || rule.type === 
                          window.CSSRule.WEBKIT_KEYFRAMES_RULE)) {
                    anims.push(rule);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return anims;
};

animList = getAnimationList();
if (animList.length == 0){
    console.log('>>> No Animations');
} else {
    console.log('>>> Number of animations is ' + animList.length);
};
    
// ... more code follows, ommitted for brevity
    
</body>
</html>
```

The error message varies by browser used as follows.

**Firefox Error**

```
Uncaught DOMException: CSSStyleSheet.cssRules getter: Not allowed to access cross-origin stylesheet script.js:32
    getAnimationList file:///C:/Users/mark/OneDrive/dev/babyclix/web/js/script.js:32
    <anonymous> file:///C:/Users/mark/OneDrive/dev/babyclix/web/js/script.js:45
```

**Edge Error**

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules
    at getAnimationList (file:///C:/Users/mark/OneDrive/dev/babyclix/web/js/script.js:32:19)
    at file:///C:/Users/mark/OneDrive/dev/babyclix/web/js/script.js:45:12
```

**Chrome Error**

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules
    at getAnimationList (file:///C:/Users/mark/OneDrive/dev/babyclix/web/js/script.js:32:19)
    at file:///C:/Users/mark/OneDrive/dev/babyclix/web/js/script.js:45:12
```

Can anyone see why the CSSRules statement would throw an error. Firefox thinks cross-domain but everything is being served from the same folder. It should make no difference if the JavaScript is included or referenced!

Comment: Possible dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48753691/cannot-access-cssrules-from-local-css-file-in-chrome-64

In short, you can't do that with `file://`. Use a local dev server instead.

Comment: @lastr2d2 Thanks that fixed my problem. Now testing using Apache and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem but this was not related to CSS but I think this may help you solve the problem.

Firstly, I noticed that your working directory is in your OneDrive directory, this causes some blocks when files try to get loaded. I encountered this problem a while ago and I fixed it by moving the project out of the OneDrive directory.

Try moving your project directory out of OneDrive and check if the error persists?

Comment: Thanks, your solution may work, I haven't tried it, instead I followed @lastr2d2  advice and that did work. Regards